# JSON Safe Values from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm using MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT()` to generate a JSON string. I then decode it in PHP with `json_decode()`.

I'm already escaping double quotes in the values like this:

```
REPLACE(COALESCE(`column_name`, ''), '"', '\\\\"')
```

My problem is that there's some other character in a record that's invalid and causing a `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` (4) when trying to decode. Rather than track down the specific character that's causing this problem, I'd like to apply a more generic solution that makes the values "safe".

[This blog](http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2015/05/hand-rolling-valid-json-in-mysql-using-group_concat/) solves the problem by using MySQL's `HEX()` function to encode the value, and then this PHP function on the decode end for each value:

```
function hexToStr($hex)
{
    $string = '';
    for ($charIter = 0; $charIter < strlen($hex) - 1; $charIter += 2)
    {
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$charIter] . $hex[$charIter + 1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that requires less work on the decode end. Ideally doing all the work in MySQL.

---

After three downvotes and close vote, I'm not sure how to better structure my question. I simply want to escape values in MySQL so that they'll be "JSON safe".

Comment: why you want to generate json string  with GROUP_CONCAT()? GROUP_CONCAT() will make the query slow. why not perform a simple query?

Comment: It never occurred to you that what you're doing is basically stupid? You're creating a JSON string in MySQL, then decoding it in PHP - what's wrong with getting the stuff out of MySQL then doing whatever with it in PHP - transforming it and encoding / decoding it? Databases aren't programming languages that transform data to various formats, they have a simple job and they do it well. You want to use a hammer to eat a soup with it. While doable, does it make any sense to do so? Alternatively, you can always use JSON UDF and make your problem go away, but the stupid part will still remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I've switch to MariaDB, and am using the `COLUMN_JSON` function, which takes care of double quote escaping, but not control characters. [Here's my new solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006900/244826).

---

**Old Solutiong**

Keep the double quote escaping in the query:

```
REPLACE(COALESCE(`column_name`, ''), '"', '\\\\"')
```

Add this function for escaping the backslash and control characters, but leaving the already escaped double quotes intact:

```
/**
 * Makes sure the JSON values built by GROUP_CONCAT() in MySQL are safe for json_decode()
 * Assumes that double quotes are already escaped
 *
 * @param string $mysql_json
 * @return string
 */
function mysql_json_escape($mysql_json)
{
    $rtn = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($mysql_json); ++$i) {
        $char = $mysql_json[$i];
        if (($char === '\\') && ($mysql_json[$i + 1] !== '"')) {
            // escape a back slash, but leave escaped double quotes intact
            $rtn .= '\\\\';
        } elseif (($ord = ord($char)) && ($ord < 32)) {
            // hex encode control characters (below ASCII 32)
            $rtn .= '\\u' . str_pad(dechex($ord), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        } else {
            $rtn .= $char;
        }
    }
    return $rtn;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$data = json_decode(mysql_json_escape($mysql_json));
```