# Encoding/Escaping JSON Control Characters

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB's [`COLUMN_JSON()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/column_json/) function. As [this bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7533) illustrates, the function properly escapes double quotes, but not other characters that should be encoded/escaped.

Here's a silly example query to demonstrate how the JSON column is created.

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_JSON(COLUMN_CREATE(
        'name', `name`,
        'value', `value`
    )) SEPARATOR ','), ']') AS `json`
FROM `settings`
```

If the `name` or `value` contain invalid JSON characters, `json_decode` will fail.

I've written a PHP function to escape/encode the value that comes from the query, but it seems like there should be a better way.

```
/**
 * Makes sure the JSON values built by COLUMN_JSON() in MariaDB are safe for json_decode()
 * Assumes that double quotes are already escaped
 *
 * @param string $mysql_json
 * @return string
 */
public static function jsonEscape($mysql_json)
{
    $rtn = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($mysql_json); ++$i) {
        $char = $mysql_json[$i];
        if (($char === '\\') && ($mysql_json[$i + 1] !== '"')) {
            // escape a backslash, but leave escaped double quotes intact
            $rtn .= '\\\\';
        } elseif (($ord = ord($char)) && ($ord < 32)) {
            // hex encode control characters (below ASCII 32)
            $rtn .= '\\u' . str_pad(dechex($ord), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        } else {
            $rtn .= $char;
        }
    }
    return $rtn;
}
```

Examine the string character-by-character like this doesn't perform well. Perhaps there's a string replacement or regular expression that would be more performant?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. The problem as _Claudio Galdiolo_ shows it is his viewer not escaping the `\n`, the problem is not in Maria DB. A newline is either `\n` or `\u000A` but certainly not `\\n`.

Comment: PHP's `json_decode()` will choke on values that come out of MariaDB's `COLUMN_JSON()` function if the values have control characters. I've verified the behavior, and found the bug report when looking for a solution.

Comment: Let's assume the bug is there. Try and see if `str_replace` or a `strpos` implementation is faster. Note that `str_replace` accepts an array of `value->replacements`. For strpos you will need to loop for all 32 characters.

Comment: @RyanVincent - There is no "original string" - COLUMN_JSON() is creating the string with values from a database column. The values in the column are not JSON safe. They contain quotes, carriage returns, etc.

Comment: @RyanVincent - Salient point. Example query added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment from [Halcyon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722762/halcyon), I switched to a `str_replace()` solution, and it performs much better! The performance difference between `trim(json_encode(13), '"')` and `'\\u' . str_pad(dechex(13), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)` is just barely better, but it makes the intent more clear.

```
private static $json_replace_search;
private static $json_replace_replace;

/**
 * Makes sure the JSON values built by GROUP_CONCAT() and COLUMN_JSON() in MariaDB are safe for json_decode()
 * Assumes that double quotes are already escaped
 *
 * @param string $mysql_json
 * @return string
 */
public static function jsonEscape($mysql_json)
{
    if (is_null(self::$json_replace_search)) {
        // initialize
        self::$json_replace_search = [];
        self::$json_replace_replace = [];
        // set up all of the control characters (below ASCII 32)
        for ($i = 0; $i < 32; ++$i) {
            self::$json_replace_search[$i] = chr($i);
            self::$json_replace_replace[$i] = trim(json_encode(self::$json_replace_search[$i]), '"');
        }
    }
    // replace them
    return str_replace(self::$json_replace_search, self::$json_replace_replace, $mysql_json);
}

/**
 *
 * @param string $mysql_json
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function jsonDecode($mysql_json)
{
    return json_decode(self::jsonEscape($mysql_json));
}
```